# WPF TextBox - How to trap and deal with Backspace and Delete events

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am trying to warn the user when they select and delete text in a wpf textbox.
I am able to trap the delete event using the previewkeydown event, but its is canceling out the delete event. Even when you press ok in the code below - deletion does not happen. I am missing something ...

```
private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Delete)
            {
                var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
                if (textbox.SelectionLength > 1)
                {
                    var result = MessageBox.Show("Delete selected?", "MyApp", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                    if (result == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: it works for me :) but your logic works if you select more than one chars >1. I just select a text (more than one) and press delete button - than it show these message box, if cancel do not delete anything, if ok deletes :) you probably contains more logic than these event. I got only these event in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This does not seem to be the proper usage of the `PreviewKeyDown` event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).  That handler seems to be meant to redirect non-standard input key events to do custom behavior.  The delete key is not considered non-standard/special.

You've got the right idea with your current code otherwise, but now you just need to actually delete the text in the textbox.

```cs
private void TextBox_KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.KeyCode)
    {
       case Keys.Delete:
            if (sender is TextBox tb)
            {
                if(tb.SelectionLength > 1 && MessageBox.Show("Delete?", "MyApp", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    tb.SelectedText = "";
                }
            }
            e.Handled = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Lastly, make sure you're actually subscribing your handlers

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   MyTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(TextBox_KeyDownHandler);
}
```

Comment: This answer does not work because the KeyDown event does not catch the Key.Delete or Key.Backspace. You need to use PreviewKeyDown in order to catch these Keys.